# Unresolved identifier handler error

Tags: json, swift, linux, rest, httphandler

I am trying to create a REST API in swift and I had an example of code that I can't fully understand.

```
import PerfectLib
import PerfectHTTP
import PerfectHTTPServer


let server = HTTPServer()
server.serverPort = 8080
server.documentRoot = "webroot"


private func getClientRoutes()->Routes{
        var routes = Routes()
        routes.add(method: .post, uri: "/client/register", handler:httpClientHandler.registerClientHandler)
        routes.add(method: .post, uri: "/client/activity", handler:httpClientHandler.registerActivityClientHandler)
        routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/client/getVPNConfig", handler:clientGetVpnConfigHandler)
        return routes
}

public func registerClientHandler(request: HTTPRequest, _ response: HTTPResponse) {
        response.setHeader(.contentType, value: "application/json")
        var clientid: String?
        if let bodyJson = request.postBodyString{
            do {
                let incoming = try bodyJson.jsonDecode() as! [String: String]
                if let i = incoming["clientid"]{
                    clientid = i
                }
            } catch {


            }
        }




        if let clientid = clientid{
            if let vpnConfigForClientDTO = clientController.registerClient(clientId: clientid){
                try! response.appendBody(string: vpnConfigForClientDTO.jsonEncodedString())


            }else{
                try! response.appendBody(string: "VPN ERROR".jsonEncodedString())
                response.status = HTTPResponseStatus.badRequest
            }


        }else{
            try! response.appendBody(string: "Lacking clientid parameter".jsonEncodedString())
            response.status = HTTPResponseStatus.badRequest
        }
        response.completed()
    }








do {
    try server.start()
} catch PerfectError.networkError(let err, let msg) {
    print("Network error thrown: \(err) \(msg)")
}
```

There is this handler `handler:httpClientHand` and I dont now why is it there and what is it? when I try to build it an error occurs saying that this handler (httpClientHand) is an unresolved identifier. And my question here is how should I modify the code so that the error isn't showing?

Comment: Where is this example from? Seems like `httpClientHandler` is unknown, so whether you're missing an `import` statement or the code itself is missing.

Comment: So how could I do it? Should I use some different handler?